# Can you search Gmail messages by who was the delegate?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search, email-headers

[Gmail's Delegate and collaborate on email](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350) allows adding delegates who are able to access someone else's mail box and read, delete and send from there. It states:

> You can add up to 10 delegates. If you're using Gmail through your
> work, school, or other organization, you can add up to 1000 delegates
> within your organization.

Is there a way to use [search operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190) to find only messages that were sent by a given delegate?

Examples that don't work (the latter two are what is actually shown in the full headers):

```
sent_by:specific_delegate@gmail.com
sender:specific_delegate@gmail.com
X-Google-Sender-Delegation:specific_delegate@gmail.com
```

Comment: Related: [1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/24861/88163), [2](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/5719/88163)